# Python dataclasses recursive definition

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

Consider the following dataclass with Python:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass()
class Foo: 
    some_id: int
    name: str
    child: Foo  # <-- failure here
```

What's the proper syntax for this recursive definition?